# Export BigQuery query result into a compressed gzip file on GCS in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to run a custom query and save the query result into a compressed csv on GCS using python. I found a quite good tutorial where I can use custom queries and it is working - except I did not find any option to set up compression: https://kashif-sohail.medium.com/export-query-result-from-bigquery-to-google-cloud-storage-using-python-89d1f516cf1e

There is another solution where I could save the result already compressed, however in this solution I have not found any option to write custom queries, only exporting a single table as it is: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#python

So what I am looking for is the combination of the two above because my query contains a join and some data masking too. The best way would be do these two things in one step, but so far I have not been able to do it. If it is not possible for sure, I assume I have 2 options. Option 1: save the query result in CSV and then compress it, or Option 2: create a (temp) table and then extract it compressed. In that case if it is solvable only in 2 steps, which way would be better (considering cost and performance too)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any solution for solving these two in one step. After some consideration I chose the 2. option: "create a (temp) table and then extract it compressed." My reasoning is that saving a query result in csv would fetch the data set, then copy it back to GCS which would require more network usage than just simply export it to GCS.